# new speakers sparking on bolts holding it in place

Tags: subaru, audio, speakers

I installed new pioneer speakers in a 2002 WRX Sedan and they are only working on and off.

I took off the door panel and started to undo the bolts that mounted the speakers and it started sparking on the bolt where it attached to the door.

Why would it be sparking on the bolts holding it in place? If I take out all the bolts that don't touch the metal door will it work?

Comment: It sounds like the speaker is grounding through the speaker frame and not through the wiring. If this is true, the speaker would not work when taking the bolts out. Not sure why it would be doing this, but it's not normal.

Comment: @Paulster2 yeah I thought that too but when you take the speaker out it works fine.

Comment: It could also be that it's not getting a good ground through the wires. A spark could occur if the ground through the bolt were better than through the wire ... path of least resistance and all.

Comment: OK that makes sense. Would this be the reason that they are is no sound coming out of them? In theory using a plastic bolt would fix this wouldn't it?

Comment: If this is the issue, I would run new ground wires (complete new speaker wires + and - really). You could also check the wiring all the way back to the head unit.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? We'd love to get an answer on this question, else it'll get closed for being too broad